# How to store permanent set max_allowed_packet mysql variable

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL version 5.5. I want increase database packet size permanently.How can i store permanently packet size in mysql .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in the my.ini file. Include the single line under [mysqld] in your file

max_allowed_packet=500M
now restart the MySQL service and you are done.

See the documentation for the further information.....https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: How can find my.ini file

Comment: what are you using linux,xampp or wamp?

Comment: Check this path In MySQL 5.5 Windows the default path for my.ini is C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server, but what are you using as a localserver

Comment: The name of your local server please, as in wamp or xampp?

Comment: C:\xampp\mysql\bin this my xampp location, the type file is Configuration_settings file name my ..or try the first one I sent.. MySQL 5.5 Windows the default path for my.ini is C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server, but what are you using as a localserver

Comment: I add your query max_allowed_packet=500M  in my my.ini file but cant save file get error Access Denied

Comment: Please tick this answer and up vote it if you don't mind only if you found my help resoucesful...You need to run what ever you opening it with eg notepad, notepad++ as an administrator

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DE56Trxx0h8  also check this one http://www.guidingtech.com/16317/run-notepad-as-admin-edit-system-files-without-errors/

Comment: I add your query in my.in file , but can't get result

Comment: run this..show GLOBAL variables like 'max_allowed_packet%';

Comment: and try setting a new one like SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;   or SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = numeric;...with a numeric number just like the above answer

Comment: When i restart my server that time previous packet data size show

Comment: Something problem here when i upload Up to 1024 KB file it's working, but i upload 1 MB file that's time file not uploading

Answer (score 0):

You have two values of max_allowed_packet in MySQL :

one on the client side : [mysql] section, [mysqldump], [client] and more.
one on the server side : [mysqld] section.
The value of max_allowed_packet you see with the command show variables like 'max_allowed_packet'; is the one on the server side.

In order to increase this value, you must increase both sides : in your server configuration file ([mysqld] section in your my.ini file) and in your client configuration file (whether your [client] or [mysql] section in your my.ini file).

This setting can be changed on the server side without restarting the server if you have the SUPER privilege with this command : mysql> SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = numeric;.

Don't forget to change the 'numeric' value by a numeric value. Don't forget to change your configuration file too otherwise this value will be reset at reboot.

Rehash from old answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45087/max-allowed-packet-in-mysql